# Facebook Send URL -- linking to application

Tags: facebook, dialog, send, encode

I'm trying to use the Facebook Send button on an external website to link users to a specific application (an instance of "MyTab") on my client's Facebook Fan page (the link to which looks something like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/ClientName?sk=app_XXX
```

I had no trouble embedding the send button on the external website, using the following code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:send href="https://www.facebook.com/ClientName?sk=app_XXX"></fb:send>
```

The problem is, the URL is truncated to **https://www.facebook.com/ClientName** when it is successfully sent.

How can I preserve the entire link so that users are sent DIRECTLY to the application?

I've tried encoding the url using "urllib" but that didn't work.

I'm stumped!

Answer (score 0):

This is due to OpenGraph meta tags in the URL you use are for Facebook Page, even for Page Tab they represent the page itself leading to link that differs from initial one you've provided.

You may create intermediate page that will handle redirection with javascript to Fanpage Tab Application and providing OpenGraph tags for content that will be displayed in message sent.